# Ublox NEO-M6 and Raspberry Pi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on the project and use neo-6m, raspberry pi 3. I follow these steps but I get an error. Please help me.

> Neo 6M VCC -----> Raspberry pi 5v        Neo 6M GND -----> Raspberry pi GND
>   Neo 6M  RX -----> Raspberry pi TX (gpio 14)    Neo 6M  TX ----->
>   Raspberry pi RX (gpio 15)

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

At the end of the file add the follwing lines:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
core_freq=250
enable_uart=1
force_turbo=1
```

`sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt` Replace the content with the follwing line (delete everything in it and write down the following content):
*`dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles`*

```
sudo reboot
sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

and this error:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gviuB.png)

Comment: did you set the speed of port to 9600, i.e.: ```sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 9600```  ?

Comment: yes,I did but this error :(